# How to create a Content pane view of nodes with common taxonomy terms (creating relared contents))

Tags: 7, views, nodes, taxonomy-terms, panels

I need to create a list of related contents to the current node with common taxonomy terms in Panels. I tried [Related Articles - a block view of nodes with common taxonomy terms](http://pixelwrapped.com/blog/related-articles-block-view-nodes-common-taxonomy-terms), it works well with blocks but I have problem with moving this idea to a `Content pane` display mode.

After following the above method I add `Term from node` relationships to get the following contexts in the Panels

[image]

and it is `Argument input` configuration of the Views pane

[image]

**The problem is this View is not available in the `Add content -> Views pane` section of the panels**. But if I remove `Argument input` configuration it will be available.

How can I create a View pane of the above block that works with panels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, I should have select `Multiple terms from node` in *Relationships* to create *Contexts* not the `Term from node`